# Why doesn't this calculator function work?

Tags: javascript

Trying to build a tip calculator where I tip a different percentage according to how much the bill came out to be. As suggested in the code below, 20% for bill < 50, 15% for bills $50-200, and 10% for bills $200+. When I run this code, I only receive a blank? Can you please advise?

```
function tipCalculator (bill) {

if (bill<50){
  var tip = 0.2*bill
  console.log(tip)
} else if (bill>=50 && bill < 200) {
  var tip1 = 0.15*bill
  console.log(tip1)
} else {
  var tip2 = 0.1*bill
  console.log(tip2)
}
  console.log(tipcalculator(10))}
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function

Comment: You wrote `tipcalculator ` wrong in the last `console.log()`. Also you are trying to call `tipCalculator()` inside itself, which will lead to a never ending loop. Lastly, you are not returning any calculated value.

Answer (score 1):

you wrote `console.log(tipcalculator(10)` 
So whatever `tipcalculator (10)` returns will be console logged. But since the function is not returning anything, it doesn't console log anything.

Try returning the tip and then console loggin and see if it works.

**Edit**
I think you meant to complete function first and then call `console.log(tipcalculator(10)` outside the function. Please correct it if that's the case.

Comment: @g4m3r2 you are putting console.log inside your function. Write it outside of your function and then try again.